# What's the point of streaming over HTTP (MPEG-DASH)?

Tags: http, streaming, protocols, network-protocols, mpeg-dash

I was reading about streaming-over-HTTP technologies such as [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) but don't really get the point. As I understand it, such protocols divide up the binary data in the media file into chunks, wraps each chunk in some kind of metadata, then stuffs these into HTTP messages and sends them to the client.

But what's the point of implementing this on top of HTTP instead of just implementing/creating a separate application layer protocol? Doesn't this just introduce more overhead and unnecessarily complicate the encoding/decoding process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transporting stuff over HTTP isn't done for the sake of efficiency since it's obviously inefficient. HTTP itself (at least until HTTP 2.0) is horribly inefficient.

The main reasons for using HTTP are simplicity, [interoperability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability) and re-usability. It's simple to understand and implement, it already exists in both servers and clients; plus it's well known by networks so it can easily pass through firewalls.

Comment: But browsers would still need to add support for standards like MPEG-DASH do be able to parse the metadata and play the media stream. Why would it be easier for them to implement MPEG-DASH rather than to all implement another protocol? - Isn't it pretty much the same?

Comment: DASH is an ISO standard which is being adopted very intensively. Most of industry big companies and decision makers (Microsoft, Google etc.) are involved in DASH Industry Forum so they drive it forward as much as they can. E.g. Youtube is now using DASH and HTML5 as default way to playback - that's a huge sign for an industry.

Comment: @Adam Yes, browsers and servers alike would still need to add support, but adding support to both over their existing infrastructure is easier than writing a new protocol from scratch. So it's easier to get the different browser and server developers to play along if the standard is easy for them to implement.

Comment: @Adam Also, since all networking equipment is familiar with HTTP, and the protocol can typically easily pass through firewalls, it's easier on the networking side as well.

Comment: @Malt It also enables caching / sending over CDNs

Comment: And ordinary (speak: cheap) HTTP server can be used to serve the files instead of having the need for streaming servers or some "exotic" servers with such a new protocol.